# How to refresh Datatable using AngularJS mvc c#?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am create one small demo for show users list.for that show list used datatabel with angularjs. my listing show very well first time.but i want to create custom filter on that tabel.i want to get pass week data and i have return query also in controller and data getting propare but i don't know how to next time bind datatable in angularjs.

here first time bind datatable code:

```
app.controller('userscontroller', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    $scope.dtColumns = [
        //DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("id", "User ID"),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("firstname", "First Name"),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("lastname", "Last Name"),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("email", "Email"),      
    ]

    debugger;
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
        url: "/api/User/GetUserList",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'searchRequest': null, fromDate: null, toDate: null },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withDisplayLength(50); 
}])
```

this is my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetUserList")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserList(string searchRequest)
{
    var UserList = db.UserInfo.ToList();

    if (searchRequest != null)
    {                
        if (searchRequest == "Past Week")
            UserList = UserList.Where(t => Convert.ToDateTime(t.registrationdate).ToString("MMM dd yyyy") == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("MMM dd yyyy")).ToList();                               
    }

    var Details = UserList.Select(h => new
    {
        h.id,
        h.firstname,
        h.lastname,
        h.registrationdate,
        h.email,
        h.contactnumber
    });
    return Json(Details);
}
```

this is my code for select past year data:

```
$scope.GetValue = function (event) {
    var Type = $scope.ddlSearch;           
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: '/api/User/GetUserList',
            data: { searchRequest: Type },
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

this is my table html :

```
<table id="entry-grid" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover"> </table>
```

i have try this code but i don't know how to reload datatable in anuglarjs.any one know then please help me for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to reassign `$scope.dtOptions`:

```
$scope.GetValue = function (event) {
   var Type = $scope.ddlSearch;
   $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
       url: "/api/User/GetUserList",
       type: "GET",
       cache: false,
       data: { 'searchRequest': Type },
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   })
   .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
   .withDisplayLength(50);
};
```

Update:
I have made a simple example (with a MVC Controller)

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetList")]
public ActionResult GetList(string psSelect)
{
    List<dynamic> loList = new List<dynamic>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(psSelect))
    {
        loList.Add(new { id = "1", firstname = "Tyler", lastname = "Durden"         });
    }
    else
    {
        loList.Add(new { id = "2", firstname = "Big", lastname = "Lebowski" });
    }

    return new MyJsonResult(loList);
}
```

View:

```
<div data-ng-controller="mainController">
    <input type="button" value="Refresh" data-ng-click="refreshList()" />
    <table id="entry-grid" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover"> </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
    url: "/Home/GetList",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    data: { 'psSelect': '' },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
})
.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
.withDisplayLength(50);

$scope.refreshList = function () {
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
        url: "/Home/GetList",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { 'psSelect': 'refresh' },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
.withDisplayLength(50);
};
```

Comment: i am try like this but that time call not getting in my controller so any idea about this wave?

Comment: hi pinBack any idea about this issue then please let me know.

Comment: can you please edited your answer what you want to say in details?

Comment: but still issue is getting i can't able see call from api side any other wave for that bind and refresh data in table.